# How to select a whole spline from the selection of one of its points?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make a plant grow along a curve with branches. The problem is easy when having a single curve to grow along a curve (using the trim curve node), but when it starts to split appart it's much harder...

I made a system that is able to detect when a growing branch comes close enough to the predefined start of a new branch and select the first point of the new branch.

Since the trim node works with spline (not with points) I then need to select the whole curve from the selection of its first point.

Is it possible?

To make this system work, I have to be able to change the "can_grow" spline attribute to *True* when the first point of the curve is set to "point_trigger". (The system that sets the first point of the curve to "point_trigger" when a growing branch comes nearby works fine")

Thank you very much! :)

[image: Whole node tree]

[image: guide curve]

[image: guide curve edit mode]

Answer (score 2):

easy solution:
use an *accumulate field* set to *Integer* and *point*.

- put the selection into *value*
- put spline index (index put through an *evaluate on domain* node set to *spline*) as *group id*.

The *total* output is your new selection.